# Unknown type name 'zend_string'

Tags: php, makefile, apc, php-5.6

I am trying to compile [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu-bc) cache extension using make && make install.

I get a compilation error regarding not being able to find `zend_string` or `zend_long`. Do you guys know what extension I would need for these?

[image: APCu]

Thanks :)

Comment: Nevermind got it from pecl instead `pecl install APCu-4.0.10`.

Comment: Those are PHP 7 type names. You're not using the right version of the extension.

Comment: Yeah realized it should be version 4.0.10. Thank. Answer is and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those types only exist in PHP 7/Zend Engine 3. You need the PHP 5 version of the extension.

Answer (score 4):

I try to run:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php7/bin/php-config
```

replace

```
./configure
```

Success.